# How to downgrade QuestDB from 6.1 to 6.0.9?

Tags: questdb

I tried to upgrade my QuestDB instance from 6.0.9 to 6.1 and the new version failed to on few tables with error in the logs

```
2021-10-28T22:34:26.1289079Z E i.q.c.m.EngineMigration failed to upgrade table path=XXXX
```

Now I cannot query / write few tables in 6.1. How can I downgrade back to 6.0.9. When I run 6.0.9 I got error for another half of my tables

```
Metadata version does not match runtime version [expected=422, actual=424]
```

How can I downgrade to back to 6.0.9?

Answer (score 0):

6.1 had an issue to upgrade some tables. To downgrade `a_table` back to 6.0.9 you need to go to `quest_root/db/a_table` directory and rename files

- `meta.v422` to `meta` overwriting existing file
- `_txn.v422` to `_txn`

You also need to delete file `quest_root/db/upgrade.d`

After that if you start QuestDB 6.0.9 `a_table` will be operational